# In Derby, is there a way to create a database table that has a column that defaults to the UTC timestamp?

Tags: sql, derby, utc

I use Derby as a solution for whitebox testing my code. In what will become my production database, I have a column that defaults to the system timestamp in UTC. However; I cannot figure out how to do this in Derby. Is there a way to set up a column like this using Derby? I've googled  for a good while now and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derby simply does not have a concept of timezones. While I was unable to solve this without complex triggers that called java methods, I found that the solution to my real problem (unit testing) was much simpler. In my unit test, I simply asserted that my returned date was off by the difference between the default timezone and UTC rather than asserting that the dates were equal (or very close).

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to post what you've tried.

This works for me in Derby 10.10:

```
ij> create table mytab (a int, b timestamp default current_timestamp);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into mytab (a) values (1);
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from mytab;
A          |B
-----------------------------------------
1          |2013-08-01 17:04:17.458

1 row selected
```

Comment: This puts in the current timestamp, but not the current UTC timestamp. The problem occurs when passing a Calendar into ResultSet.getTimestamp(column, calendar). Oracle expects it to be in UTC and thus I get it correctly. Derby doesn't have any timezone concept so the driver will think its in UTC and then translate it to local time. Except it's in local time, so I'll get back local time minus the offset.

In other words, I want to store an exact point in time and not a calendar date.